# adding file size of two or more files in powershell

Tags: powershell

Why is the following snippet only adding the byte-size of the last file to 0 and not the size of all files matching?

```
$sizeOfVhds = 0
(Get-Item "\\blahhh.com\foo\bar\*.vhd") |
ForEach-Object {
    $sizeOfVhds = $sizeOfVhds + $_.length
}
```

I'm trying to sum the size of two or more vhd files in a given directory. I'm *not* trying to calculate the human readable size.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with PS, but [`get-item`](http://ss64.com/ps/get-item.html) will only get a single object. Don't you want [`get-childitem`](http://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) since you want an array with all VHDs?

Comment: @nixda does have at least part of your problem. Combine it with measure item

Comment: hard to believe ... but a reboot solved my Problem. The above code and the solution of @nixda worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easier way to do this using the `measure-object` cmdlet. Here's an example where you can assume `$Files` contains a collection of [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) objects.

```
PS C:\> $Files | measure-object -Property length -sum


Count    : 61
Average  :
Sum      : 167476924
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Length
```

Here's an example using the input you provided that extracts the sum in a single statement:

```
PS C:\> $sum = ((Get-ChildItem "\\blahhh.com\foo\bar\*.vhd") | 
        Measure-Object -Property length -sum) | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
PS C:\> $sum
Sum of the value of 'length' for each object in collection outputted here
```